# Need regexp with condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

It is necessary to check string. It should contain one substring AND dont contain other substring. This should works only with regexp.

Examples. We accept string with 'fruit' substring, but don't accept string contains substring 'love':

```
We all love green fruit. -> dont match
We all love to walk. -> dont match
We all green fruit. -> match
```

Write one regex if it possible.

```
/(?<!love).+fruit/ dont work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, you can achieve what you want with `strpos`, but you specified you only need a regex solution. Note that this is not the best approach for this task *unless* you need to check for the substrings in a *specific context* (like within word boundaries, or after or before specific symbols, etc.)

The [`(?<!love).+fruit`](https://regex101.com/r/jP6fB1/1) regex matches any 1+ characters that are not preceded with `love` substring up to the `fruit` substring. It will match `I love fruit` because the lookbehind asserts true at the beginning of the string, then `.+` grabs the whole string, then backtracking does its job to get `fruit`.

In fact, you only need 1 lookahead to check if there is no `love` anchored at the start of the string:

```
^(?!.*love).*fruit
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM7bG0/1)

You only check for the substring `love` with `(?!.*love)` at the beginning of the string (due to `^`), and then, if it is missing, the regex goes on matching any characters (other than a newline if `/s` modifier is not use) up to the last `fruit`.

Here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9IsiHA):

```
$re = "/^(?!.*love).*fruit/"; 
if (preg_match($re, "We all love green fruit."))
{ 
   echo "Matched!";  // Won't be displayed since there is no match
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work

```
^(?!.*\blove\b)(?=.*\bfruit\b).*
 <------------><------------->
   Don't match    Match this
    this word        word
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wD3qR8/1)**

**NOTE** :- You can remove `\b` if you assume to match `substring`..